# Parse forest from an ambiguous grammar

Tags: parsers, ambiguity

Parser-generators like `nearleyjs` can return a parse forest instead of a parse tree.

Since not all input may result in a parse forest *(eg, the input may exercise only a non-ambiguous subset of the grammar)*, how do you programmatically choose the 'correct' parse tree from the forest?

One option is to always choose the first element from the array of parse-trees returned.

Another option is to flag the returning of a parse-forest (instead of a single tree) as an error. But then, this would defy the whole point of having Earley-like parsers that allow parsing of ambiguous grammars!

Also, since only some input may result in a parse-forest (instead of a single parse-tree), how do you rule out surprises in a live/Production environment? *Assumption: For non-trivial or non-trivially long grammars, it's not humanly possible to create tests that cover all inputs.*

Comment: It sounds like you approach the question from the wrong end. **Why** do you parse at all (i.e. what's the exact problem are you trying to solve)? `this would defy the whole point of having Earley-like parsers that allow parsing of ambiguous grammars!` - it doesn't matter what's the point of Earley-like parsers. The only thing that matters whether your selected approach solves your problem. In other words, `how do you programmatically choose the 'correct' parse tree` is entirely up to you to define, depending on what you want. Whether you need the entire forest or not depends on your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use such a parser, you need some external way to select among the possible trees in the forest.  Typically there are additional constraints beyond what is encoded in the context-free grammar, which can be used to identify the correct parse.  In other words, there are some rules that are part of the syntax (they are part of the context-free grammar, and thus handled by the parser), and some rules that are part of the semantics; there may be multiple parses that are compatable with the syntax rules, and then the semantic rules are used to select which one complies with the semantic rules.